# NSTimer performance

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstimer

I have a Foundation CLI tool that uses 5 NSTimers to execute different methods in the background.  Ever since implementing these timers (rather than a while loop or similar), I've noticed the CPU usage of the program skyrocket.  Does anyone have any information on this?

EDIT:

Here's a code snippet (only 3 timers are currently implemented):

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(executeInterval0Update) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(executeInterval1Update) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(executeInterval2Update) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

[runLoop run];
```

Comment: are you sure you're not continuously creating timers?

Comment: I don't believe so.  I added an edit, showing the extent of the timers.

Comment: Rather than guess, measure using a profiling tool. The one built into Activity Monitor is easy to use and should be enough to get you started. Or look into using Instruments.